# ArcMap remote desktop connection error with Windows10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, graphics, remote-desktop

Issue with ArcMap 10.5 (and above) with Windows10. For some reason I have been getting the following error when trying to start an instance during a remote desktop session (most probably related to the graphics card).

> LoadLibrary failed with error 87:The parameter is incorrect.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found that I actually had to DISABLE the group policy for "*Use hardware graphics adapters for all Remote Desktop Services sessions*" listed below.

Enabling did not resolve it--disabling and restarting did.
The other two policies had no effect.

> Here's how I solved the problem (Edit Group Policy tool from Control 
>   Panel):
>
> - Right click on Windows start menu and select Run (or windows+R)
> - type `cmd`
> - type `gpedit.exe`
> - go to "*Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop
>     Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Remote Session Environment*"
> - set the following parameters to `Enabled`
>
>   - Use hardware graphics adapters for all Remote Desktop Services sessions
>   - Prioritize H.264/AVC 444 graphics mode for Remote Desktop Connections
>   - Configure H.264/AVC hardware encoding for Remote Desktop Connections

Comment: After Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903 (4/9/2020) I also needed to set the it to Disabled to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved the problem (**Edit Group Policy tool from Control Panel**):

-Right click on Windows start menu and select **Run** (or windows+R)

-type **cmd**

-type **gpedit.exe**

-go to: Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session Environment

-set the following parameters to **Enabled**

```
Use hardware graphics adapters for all Remote Desktop Services sessions

Prioritize H.264/AVC 444 graphics mode for Remote Desktop Connections

Configure H.264/AVC hardware encoding for Remote Desktop Connections
```

EDIT: After Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903 (4/9/2020) I needed to set the following to **Disabled** (same as @gisIT comments below)

```
Use hardware graphics adapters for all Remote Desktop Services sessions
```

Answer (score 1):

It was necessary for me to set "use WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections" to disabled in order to fix this problem.

I have Windows 10 - version 2004 and ArcGIS ArcMap 10.7.

The following are all set to enabled:
- Use hardware graphics adapters for all Remote Desktop Services sessions
- Prioritize H.264/AVC 444 graphics mode for Remote Desktop Connections
- Configure H.264/AVC hardware encoding for Remote Desktop Connections