# ArcMap Remote Desktop Connection Error LoadLibrary failed with error 126

Tags: arcmap, error, remote-desktop

Environment:
ArcMap 10.6.1 loaded on Windows 10 PC
RemoteApp with Remote Desktop application
Windows 8 PC (used for remote access)

Issue:
ArcMap 10.6.1 works as expected when logged directly into the PC it is loaded on.  However, now that we are teleworking, I am using a Windows 8 PC to access my Organization's RemoteApp application and use Remote Desktop to log into my computer.  I am able to open ArcCatalog and all connections are listed.  However, if I click on a feature class to preview, I get an error that says, "LoadLibrary failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found." Also, if I try to open ArcMap I get the same message.

Troubleshooting:
First, we had other users attempt to use Remote Desktop to access the PC and open ArcMap. Other users received the same error message ("LoadLibrary failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found.")
Next, we edited group policy and Enabled parameters in the Remote Session Environment per 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354868/160425  (thanks for that!)

We tested again and found that some users could now open ArcMap with no problem using Remote Desktop, however others are still unable to.

Here are our test results so far:
*  [User1] VPN from PC with Windows 10 + Remote Desktop = ArcMap works as expected
*  [User2] RemoteApp from PC with Windows 7 + Remote Desktop = ArcMap works as expected
*   [User2] RemoteApp from PC with Windows 10 + Remote Desktop  = Error: “LoadLibrary failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found"
*  [User3] RemoteApp from PC with Windows 8.1 + Remote Desktop  = Error: “LoadLibrary failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found"
*  [User4] PC on Org Network with Windows 10 + Remote Desktop  = Error: “LoadLibrary failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found"

Comment: Having the same issue with ArcMap 10.7! Was working but now it isn't some users it works, other users it doesn't ???

Answer (score 1):

We finally found that our issue was related to the file atio6axx.dll that is part of the driver package for the AMD Radeon card:

1. Searched the computer and found the file located in C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\u0352938.inf_amd64_e098709f94aef08d\B352876 folder.
2. Copied the file into C:\windows\system32 folder.
3. Ran ArcMap from remote access and it works.

Also, Esri provided the following solution.  It didn't work for us, but it may work for others:
(Technical Support - Problem: Graphics card conflict may cause ArcMap to crash)

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013717